# How to get client ip address using gorilla/mux - GoLang

Tags: go, mux

I am implementing an API application in golang using gorilla/mux which is a powerfull library, tends to help to build web APIs,

However i need to keep ip address for each client for that how can i get ip address for each client who visits website?

Code:

```golang
func GetIpAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    // Whenever User visits this URL (this function)
    // We have to know IP Address of user
    output := r.UserAgent()
    fmt.Print("Output : ", output)
    // But var (output) returns whole string excluding clients ip address
}
```

Comment: Can you include some of the code you've written so far?

Comment: @17xande There you go...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request.RemoteAddr`
You should also take a look at the `X-Forwarded-For` header in case this code runs behind a firewall, load balancer or other service.

```
func GetIpAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ip := r.RemoteAddr
    xforward := r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")
    fmt.Println("IP : ", ip)
    fmt.Println("X-Forwarded-For : ", xforward)
}
```